# Get all the event-handlers of a event declared in a custom user-control

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, delegates, event-handling

I'm trying to write a universal function that, given a reference to a control/component and the name of an event declared on its class, it should be able to retrieve (through **Reflection**) all the event-handlers currently registered for the specified event name.

The first and main problem I had (which is solved, so you can ignore this paragraph), is that all the solutions (mostly written in C#) that I found in StackOverflow are limited in the meaning that the authors only look for the event-field declaration in the `System.Windows.Forms.Control` class, and for that reason will fail for example when trying to retrieve the event-handlers of `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.MouseEnter` event (since the event-field is declared in `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem` class), and also does not take into account event-fields naming of `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class, which have a underscore. 
So I covered all this, and currently my solution works (or I think it works) for any class that inherits from `System.ComponentModel.Component`.

The only problem I'm having now is when I declare a custom type (that inherits from **Control** / **UserControl** / **Component** / **Form** etc. class) and I pass that type to my function. In this circumstance I get a null-reference exception. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

```
Public Shared Function GetEventHandlers(component As IComponent, eventName As String) As IReadOnlyCollection(Of [Delegate])

    Dim componentType As Type
    Dim declaringType As Type ' The type on which the event is declared.
    Dim eventInfo As EventInfo
    Dim eventField As FieldInfo = Nothing
    Dim eventFieldValue As Object
    Dim eventsProp As PropertyInfo
    Dim eventsPropValue As EventHandlerList
    Dim eventDelegate As [Delegate]
    Dim invocationList As [Delegate]()

    ' Possible namings for an event field.
    Dim eventFieldNames As String() =
            {
                $"Event{eventName}",            ' Fields declared in 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' class.
                $"EVENT_{eventName.ToUpper()}", ' Fields declared in 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' class.
                $"{eventName}Event"             ' Fields auto-generated.
            }

    Const bindingFlagsEventInfo As BindingFlags =
              BindingFlags.ExactBinding Or
              BindingFlags.Instance Or
              BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
              BindingFlags.Public Or
              BindingFlags.Static

    Const bindingFlagsEventField As BindingFlags =
              BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or
              BindingFlags.ExactBinding Or
              BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or
              BindingFlags.Instance Or
              BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
              BindingFlags.Static

    Const bindingFlagsEventsProp As BindingFlags =
              BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or
              BindingFlags.ExactBinding Or
              BindingFlags.Instance Or
              BindingFlags.NonPublic

    Const bindingFlagsEventsPropValue As BindingFlags =
              BindingFlags.Default

    componentType = component.GetType()
    eventInfo = componentType.GetEvent(eventName, bindingFlagsEventInfo)
    If (eventInfo Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException($"Event with name '{eventName}' not found in type '{componentType.FullName}'.", NameOf(eventName))
    End If

    declaringType = eventInfo.DeclaringType

    For Each name As String In eventFieldNames
        eventField = declaringType.GetField(name, bindingFlagsEventField)
        If (eventField IsNot Nothing) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next name

    If (eventField Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException($"Field with name 'Event{eventName}', 'EVENT_{eventName.ToUpper()}' or '{eventName}Event' not found in type '{declaringType.FullName}'.", NameOf(eventName))
    End If

#If DEBUG Then
    Debug.WriteLine($"Field with name '{eventField.Name}' found in type '{declaringType.FullName}'")
#End If

    eventFieldValue = eventField.GetValue(component)
    eventsProp = GetType(Component).GetProperty("Events", bindingFlagsEventsProp, Type.DefaultBinder, GetType(EventHandlerList), Type.EmptyTypes, Nothing)
    eventsPropValue = DirectCast(eventsProp.GetValue(component, bindingFlagsEventsPropValue, Type.DefaultBinder, Nothing, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), EventHandlerList)
    eventDelegate = eventsPropValue.Item(eventFieldValue)
    invocationList = eventDelegate.GetInvocationList()

    If (invocationList Is Nothing) Then ' There is no event-handler registered for the specified event.
        Return Enumerable.Empty(Of [Delegate]).ToList()
    End If

    Return invocationList

End Function
```

The exception occurs at this line:

```
invocationList = eventDelegate.GetInvocationList()
```

because `eventDelegate` is null.

---

To test the exception, you can take this class as example:

```
Public Class TestUserControl : Inherits UserControl

    Event TestEvent As EventHandler(Of EventArgs)

    Overridable Sub OnTestEvent(e As EventArgs)
        If (Me.TestEventEvent IsNot Nothing) Then
            RaiseEvent TestEvent(Me, e)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

And a example usage like this:

```
Dim ctrl As New TestUserControl()

AddHandler ctrl.TestEvent, Sub()
                               Debug.WriteLine("Hello World!")
                           End Sub

Dim handlers As IReadOnlyCollection(Of [Delegate]) = 
    GetEventHandlers(ctrl, NameOf(TestUserControl.TestEvent))

For Each handler As [Delegate] In handlers
    Console.WriteLine($"Method Name: {handler.Method.Name}")
Next
```

Not sure if maybe it is an issue related to the binding flags, or maybe the event field naming... but I don't have this null-reference object issue when trying the same with any built-in control/component class that expose events, instead of that `TestUserControl` class.

What I'm doing wrong?, and how do I fix it?. Please note that this function should still be universal.

Comment: Thanks for comment but in no way adding a null-check for **eventDelegate** could solve the problem, because the problem is that it shouldn't be null, and the return value of **GetEventHandlers** function rely on **eventDelegate** object not being null. When testing the **GetEventHandlers** function passing to its parameters built-in classes/controls to retrieve a list of event-handlers for an event that does not have registered event-handlers/delegates, **eventDelegate** never is null. When doing the same with the **TestUserControl** class, it is always null... when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Component.Events is only used for the predefined Winforms events.   So not TestEvent, you're doomed to get Nothing.  Just help less, you already got what you were looking for.  Get ahead by changing the declaration to Dim eventFieldValue As MulticastDelegate, now you simply return eventFieldValue.GetInvocationList()

Comment: @Hans Passant Many thanks for the tips!. Please feel free to publish an answer if you want, just to mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to what @**Hans Passant** suggested in his commentary in the main question, this is working as expected:

```
Public Function GetEventHandlers(component As IComponent, eventName As String) As IReadOnlyCollection(Of [Delegate])

    Dim componentType As Type = component.GetType()

    ' Find event declaration in the source type.
    Dim eventInfo As EventInfo = componentType.GetEvent(eventName, BindingFlags.ExactBinding Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static)
    If (eventInfo Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException($"Event with name '{eventName}' not found in type '{componentType.FullName}'.", NameOf(eventName))
    End If

    ' The type on which the event is declared.
    Dim declaringType As Type = eventInfo.DeclaringType

    ' Find event-field declaration in the declaring type.
    Dim eventField As FieldInfo = Nothing

    ' Possible namings for an event field.
    Dim eventFieldNames As String() = {
        $"Event{eventName}",            ' Fields declared in 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' class.
        $"EVENT_{eventName.ToUpper()}", ' Fields declared in 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' class.
        $"{eventName}Event"             ' Fields (auto-generated) declared in other classes.
    }

    For Each name As String In eventFieldNames
        eventField = declaringType.GetField(name, BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or BindingFlags.ExactBinding Or BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static)
        If (eventField IsNot Nothing) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next name

    If (eventField Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException($"Field with name '{String.Join("' or '", eventFieldNames)}' not found in declaring type '{declaringType.FullName}'.", NameOf(eventName))
    End If

#If DEBUG Then
    Debug.WriteLine($"Field with name '{eventField.Name}' found in declaring type '{declaringType.FullName}'")
#End If

    Dim eventFieldValue As object = eventField.GetValue(component)
    If TypeOf eventFieldValue Is MulticastDelegate
        ' See @Hans Passant comment:
        ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763972/get-all-the-event-handlers-of-a-event-declared-in-a-custom-user-control?noredirect=1#comment100177090_56763972

        Return DirectCast(eventFieldValue, MulticastDelegate).GetInvocationList()
    End If

    Dim eventsProp As PropertyInfo = GetType(Component).GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or BindingFlags.ExactBinding Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic, Type.DefaultBinder, GetType(EventHandlerList), Type.EmptyTypes, Nothing)
    Dim eventsPropValue As EventHandlerList = DirectCast(eventsProp.GetValue(component, BindingFlags.Default, Type.DefaultBinder, Nothing, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), EventHandlerList)
    Dim eventDelegate As [Delegate] = eventsPropValue.Item(eventFieldValue)
    Dim invocationList As [Delegate]() = eventDelegate?.GetInvocationList()

    If (invocationList Is Nothing) Then ' There is no event-handler registered for the specified event.
       Return Enumerable.Empty(Of [Delegate]).ToList()
    End If

    Return invocationList

End Function
```

Also we can define the next method extension for **EventInfo** type to act as a method overload for [EventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(Object, Delegate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.eventinfo.removeeventhandler?view=netframework-4.8):

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Removes an event handler from an event source.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code>
''' Public Class Form1
''' 
'''     Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
'''         Dim target As Form = Me
'''         Dim eventInfo As EventInfo = target.GetType().GetEvent(NameOf(Form.Click))
'''         eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(target, NameOf(Me.Form1_Click))
'''     End Sub
''' 
'''     Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
'''         MsgBox(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)
'''     End Sub
''' 
''' End Class
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <param name="eventInfo">
''' The event information.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="target">
''' The event source.
''' </param>
''' 
''' <param name="handlerName">
''' The name of the delegate to be disassociated from the events raised by <paramref name="target"/>.
''' <para></para>
''' Note that the name is case-sensitive.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Extension>
Public Sub RemoveEventHandler(eventInfo As EventInfo, target As IComponent, handlerName As String)

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(handlerName)
        Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(handlerName))
    End If

    For each handler As [Delegate] in GetEventHandlers(target, eventInfo.Name)
        If handler.Method.Name.Equals(handlerName, StringComparison.Ordinal)
            eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(target, handler)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next handler
    Throw New ArgumentException($"No delegate was found with the specified name: '{handlerName}'", NameOf(handlerName))

End Sub
```